# "pytest" is not accessed / Import "pytest" could not be resolved - Pylance

Tags: python, pytest, pylance

I haven't touched python in a long time and I forgot how much of a pain importing can be.

So I'm using pylance and pipenv as my shell. I have pytest installed in my local env, I can run pytest from the command line and test my code. However, I can't import it in the same file I'm running my tests from. Any idea what might be causing that problem?

Python version 3.9

I have my tests in a separate file right below root. I don't have a **init**.py file in tests. I've read that that can cause problems.

Comment: Make sure to install `pytest` in the environment selected in VS Code, using the `pip` or `python` command from that environment, eg `.venv/bin/python -m pip install pytest`

Answer (score 3):

probably **Pylance** is having problems with the *path* for `site-packages` folder for your *virtual environment* and returns `Import "pytest" could not be resolved`, you need to set **python** path in this way:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/my/project/path/.venv/bin/python"
```

Comment: Sorry again, I'm really bad at knowing about how python works on my machine. Is this a variable that I add to my pipfile? Or is this something that I need to find in a dir on my computer somewhere?

Comment: this must be declared in settings to run the program using `visual studio`

Comment: Try add correspondingly to `/.vscode/settings.json`

Comment: I had tried adding to this to my User vscode settings (`~/.vscode/settings.json`) as a relative path but it wasn't working, but adding it to my project vscode settings (`/path/to/project/.vscode/settings.json`) as an absolute path worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I tried h. deville fletcher's answer and it didn't seem to work for me, but I could have messed up in there too. However, in the process, I remembered that I hadn't changed my interpreter. Once I changed the interpreter to my pipenv shell that fixed my problem.